# Wix table can't sort

Tags: velo

[image]

Hi, I've created a Collection in Wix and pasted it on my website as a table.
Wix has automatically sorted it by the second field (right column on the screenshot) Largest - > Smallest. I can't figure out a way how to sort this table the way I want.
I basically need to turn the order upside down:

[image]